# Java check if function is already called

Tags: java

I want to check if the instance of the obj is already called. For instance, if sits the for the first time it will say "Sits" but if I call it again it will say "I am doing nothing" because the Cat is already sat. This applies for the other instances..

```
public class UseCatRenat{
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       CatRenat renat = new CatRenat();
       System.out.println("Renat says: "+ renat.standsUp());
       System.out.println("Renat says: "+ renat.sits());
       System.out.println("Renat says: "+ renat.sits());
   }
}

public class CatRenat{
      public String StandsUp(){
      return "I am standing up";
      }
      public String sits(){ 
      return "Sits";
      }
}
```

**Current output:**

```
 Renat says: I am standig up 
 Renat says: Sits
 Renat says: Sits
```

**Expected output:**

```
Renat says: I am standig up 
Renat says: Sits
Renat says: I am doing nothing
```

Comment: Introduce a `private boolean alreadyCalled = false` that you query and update according to your rules.

Comment: You need to store the state of Renat.  In this case, it's a boolean state.  It has two options: Either Renat is standing, or it's sitting.  Try googling **"instance variables"**, there are plenty of Java tutorials online that can bring you up to speed on the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CatRenat {
    private boolean hasSat = false;

    public String StandsUp() {
        return "I am standing up";
    }

    public String sits() { 
         if (hasSat) {
             return "I am doing nothing";
         } else {
             hasSat = true;
             return "Sits";
         }
    }
}
```

Use a boolean variable to track the change.